# Jquery, замена параметра a href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день! Есть ссылка типа

```
https://site.ru/ru-RU/Init?SYSTEM=3&ID=870e061a-df18-479c-9682-dfbb16c5f370&AMOUNT=0.00&DESC=Test
```

нужно в сылке изменить один параметр, не трогая остальные, тем более они всегда разные, например изменить вот этот

```
AMOUNT
```

Я пробую вот так

```
$('a.class').attr('href', val.replace(/AMOUNT=[^&]+/, 'AMOUNT='+MyValue));
```

но так не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: а это нормально, что у вас AMOUNT идет сразу за значением предыдущего параметра без разделителя '&'?

Comment: У вас и правда все параметры идут одной непонятной строкой в строке? Или все же между `dfbb16c5f370` и  `AMOUNT` есть символ `&` ? А по делу, как генерируется ссылка? Нельзя сразу генерировать нормальную?

Comment: А что значит - не работает? Никакой замены вообще не произошло? Или заменилось не так как вы ожидали? Покажите, какая ссылка получилась после замены?

Comment: Там изначально мой косяк, там был разделитель, просто я когда писал пост его нечаянно стёр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI битая.
Параметры разделяются амперсандом (`&`):

```
https://site.ru/ru-RU/Init?SYSTEM=3&ID=870e061a-df18-479c-9682-dfbb16c5f370&AMOUNT=0.00&DESC=Test
```

Из такой строки можно заменить уже вот так:

```js
$(e => {
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let link = this.href.replace(/(AMOUNT=)([^&]+)/, "$01123");
    
    this.href = link;
    this.innerHTML = link;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='https://site.ru/ru-RU/Init?SYSTEM=3&ID=870e061a-df18-479c-9682-dfbb16c5f370&AMOUNT=0.00&DESC=Test'>https://site.ru/ru-RU/Init?SYSTEM=3&ID=870e061a-df18-479c-9682-dfbb16c5f370&AMOUNT=0.00&DESC=Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

В той ссылке, которую вы привели, символ & есть только после первого параметра. А после второго и третьего нет.

Соответственно, кусочек регулярки [^&] ни на что не срабатывает.

Comment: Вроде же сработает просто от начала слова `AMOUNT` и до конца строки. Так как не найдет в текущем примере символа `&` ?